# ViewPart hangs on click of JButton

Tags: swing, swt, swingworker

I am working on Teamcenter RAC customization. I have changed an existing code which deals with viewpart and jbuttons on it. The viewpart(SWT) loads a stylesheet rendering panel. the problem is whenever I click on the save button (JButton) this hangs the teamcenter application on post -executing activities. 
The code is as follows:

```
saveCheckOutButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed( ActionEvent paramAnonymousActionEvent )
            {
                final AbstractRendering sheetPanel = itemPanel.getStyleSheetPanel();
                final AbstractRendering sheetPanel1 = itemRevPanel.getStyleSheetPanel();
                SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground()
                        throws Exception
                    {
                        if(pPanel==null)
                            return null;
                        if( pPanel.isPanelSavable())
                        {

                            if(sheetPanel==null|| sheetPanel1==null)
                                return null;

                            sheetPanel.saveRendering();
                            sheetPanel1.saveRendering(); 
                            /*if(!sheetPanel.getErrorFlag() && !sheetPanel1.getErrorFlag())
                            {
                              sheetPanel.setModifiable( false );
                              sheetPanel1.setModifiable( false );
                            }*/
                        }
                        return null;
                    }
                    @Override
                    protected void done(){
                        if(!sheetPanel.getErrorFlag() && !sheetPanel1.getErrorFlag())
                        {
                          sheetPanel.setModifiable( false );
                          sheetPanel1.setModifiable( false );
                        }
                    }
                };

                worker.execute(); 

            }
        } );
```

I have written the code under swingworker as suggested by some of the experts here but to no success. Request for some immediate help.

Comment: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: I am not too sure about that. So I mentioned that in my question itself as immediate.

Comment: Mixing Swing with SWT is not recommended as it can be very difficult to get things working properly. Each system has its own UI dispatch queue which don't coexist very well.

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "it hangs the teamcenter application". Whether it responds too slow or doInBackground() is not properly executed?

Anyway you can try executing your rendering code in `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` and use the method `get()`. If you don't call get() in the done method, you will lose all the exceptions that the computation in the doInBackground() has thrown. So we will get to know about exception if any is there.

SwingUtilities.invokeLater() allows a task to be executed at some later point in time, as the name suggests; but more importantly, the task will be executed on the AWT event dispatch thread. Refer [Invoke later API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#invokeLater(java.lang.Runnable)) for the detailed info.

**About get():**

Waits if necessary for the computation to complete, and then retrieves its result.

**Note:** calling get on the Event Dispatch Thread blocks all events, including repaints, from being processed until this SwingWorker is complete.

```
saveCheckOutButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent paramAnonymousActionEvent) {
                final AbstractRendering sheetPanel = itemPanel.getStyleSheetPanel();
                final AbstractRendering sheetPanel1 = itemRevPanel.getStyleSheetPanel();
                SwingWorker<Void, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<Void, Void>() {

                    @Override
                    protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {
                        if (pPanel == null)
                            return null;
                        if (pPanel.isPanelSavable()) {
                            if (sheetPanel == null || sheetPanel1 == null)
                                return null;

                            saveRendering();
                        }
                        return null;
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void done() {
                        try {
                            get();
                            if (!sheetPanel.getErrorFlag() && !sheetPanel1.getErrorFlag()) {
                                sheetPanel.setModifiable(false);
                                sheetPanel1.setModifiable(false);
                            }
                        } catch (final InterruptedException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex);
                        } catch (final ExecutionException ex) {
                            throw new RuntimeException(ex.getCause());
                        }

                    }
                };
                worker.execute();
            }
        });



        private void saveRendering() {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                sheetPanel.saveRendering();
                sheetPanel1.saveRendering();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: It doesn't gets properly executed. I tried the above suggestion but the result was same. The client becomes not responding and the weird part is the save button hangs the application only when the user logs into Teamcenter & creates a new object and try to do some save into it. But it works fine for existing objects in a new session.

Comment: @user1957902. Do you receive any exception when the application was not responsive?